# After DB migration, getting CodecNotFoundException during insert operation with UDT Type field

Tags: java, cassandra, database-migration, cassandra-3.0

I am migrating my dB from one release(1.X) to another(1.Y) keeping my Application(1.X) pod running. Application is having cql ddl scripts as well(to update db via cqlsh).

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT exists my_optional_params (
validity_period map <text,text>,
refresh ascii,
my_flag boolean
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT exists table_X (
id timeuuid,
name text,
description text,
owner text,
optional_params frozen< my_optional_params >,
PRIMARY KEY ((tenant_name), id)
) WITH gc_grace_seconds = 86400
AND comment = 'table X';
```

In release 1.Y, I have added an alter script to add an additional field in **UDT type** my_optional_params.

```
ALTER TYPE my_optional_params add refresh_context map <text,text>;
```

Now, after migrating dB from 1.X to 1.Y, my Application(running on 1.X and using migrated dB(1.Y)) is throwing CodecNotFoundException during an insert data usecase.

Here are the Entity and UDT Type model files:

MyEntity.java

```
public class MyEntity {

    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private String owner;

    private MyOptionalParams optionalParams = new MyOptionalParams();

    //getter,setters,equals,hashcode,toString()
}
```

UDT Type model :

```
public class MyOptionalParams implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3828918307164974977L;

    private ValidityPeriod validityPeriod;

    private String refresh;

    private boolean myFlag = false;


    //getter,setters,equals,hashcode,toString()
}
```

And the dao where exception is coming:

```
public class MyDummyDao implements DummyDAO {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Log.getLogger(MyDummyDao.class);


    @Inject
    private CassandraConnection connection;

    MyDummyDao() {
        // Default constructor to allow application scope
    }

    @Override
    public void storeData(MyEntity pEntity) {
        final PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getInsertPreparedStatement();
        final BoundStatement boundStatement = preparedStatement.bind()
                .setUuid("id", pEntity.getId())
                .setString("name", pEntity.getName())
                .setString("description", pEntity.getDescription())
                .setString("owner", pEntity.getOwner())
                .set("optional_params", pEntity.getOptionalParams(), MyOptionalParams.class);

        connection.getCqlSession().execute(boundStatement);
    }
    
    PreparedStatement getInsertPreparedStatement() {
        if (psInsert == null) {
            psInsert = this.prepare(
                    QueryBuilder.insertInto("my_keyspace", "table_X")
                            .value("id", QueryBuilder.bindMarker())
                            .value("name", QueryBuilder.bindMarker())
                            .value("description", QueryBuilder.bindMarker())
                            .value("owner", QueryBuilder.bindMarker())
                            .value("optional_params", QueryBuilder.bindMarker()));

        }
        return psInsert;
    }
    
     public PreparedStatement prepare(Insert query) {
        return this.prepareStatement((BuildableQuery)(query));
    }

    private PreparedStatement prepareStatement(BuildableQuery buildableQuery) {
        return this.connection.getCqlSession().prepare(buildableQuery.build());
    }
}
```

I have also defined a TypeCodec for my UDT type mapping:

```
public class MyOptionalParamsTypeCodec implements TypeCodec<MyOptionalParams> {

    static final String VP = "validity_period";

    static final String KEY_REFRESH = "refresh";

    static final String KEY_MYFLAG = "my_flag";

    

    private final TypeCodec<UdtValue> innerCodec;

    private final UserDefinedType userType;

    private final DataType cqlType;

    private final GenericType<MyOptionalParams> javaType;

    public MyOptionalParamsTypeCodec(TypeCodec<UdtValue> innerCodec, Class<MyOptionalParams> javaType) {
        this.cqlType = innerCodec.getCqlType();
        this.javaType = GenericType.of(javaType);
        this.innerCodec = innerCodec;
        this.userType = (UserDefinedType) innerCodec.getCqlType();
    }

    OptionalParamsToUDTTransformer<MyOptionalParams, UdtValue> optionalParamsToUDTTransformer = (optionalParams, udtValue) -> {
        if (optionalParams != null) {
            if (optionalParams.getValidityPeriod() != null) {
                Map<String, String> vpMap = new HashMap<>();
                vpMap.put("unit", optionalParams.getValidityPeriod().getMode().name());
                vpMap.put("value", optionalParams.getValidityPeriod().getValue().toString());
                udtValue = udtValue.setMap(VP, vpMap, String.class, String.class);
            }
            if (optionalParams.getRefresh() != null) {
                udtValue = udtValue.setString(KEY_REFRESH, optionalParams.getRefresh());
            } else {
                udtValue = udtValue.setString(KEY_REFRESH, "");
            }      

           
        }

        return udtValue;
    };

    Function<UdtValue, MyOptionalParams> udtToOptionalParamsTransformer = (udtValue) -> {
        MyOptionalParams MyOptionalParams = new MyOptionalParams();
        if (udtValue != null) {
            Map<String, String> vpInfo = udtValue.getMap(VP, String.class, String.class);
            if (vpInfo != null && vpInfo.size() > 0) {
                final String vpUnit = vpInfo.get("unit");
                final Integer vpValue = Integer.valueOf(vpInfo.get("value"));
                MyOptionalParams.setValidityPeriod(new ValidityPeriod(VPMode.valueOf(vpUnit), vpValue));
            }
            MyOptionalParams
                    .setRefresh(udtValue.getString(KEY_REFRESH))
                    .setMyFlag(udtValue.getBoolean(KEY_MYFLAG));
        }       
        return MyOptionalParams;
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ByteBuffer encode(
            @Nullable MyOptionalParams MyOptionalParams,
            @NonNull ProtocolVersion protocolVersion) {
        return this.innerCodec.encode(optionalParamsToUDTTransformer.apply(MyOptionalParams, this.userType.newValue()), protocolVersion);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public MyOptionalParams decode(
            @Nullable ByteBuffer byteBuffer,
            @NonNull ProtocolVersion protocolVersion) {
        return this.udtToOptionalParamsTransformer.apply(this.innerCodec.decode(byteBuffer, protocolVersion));
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public MyOptionalParams parse(@Nullable String value) {
        return value == null || value.isEmpty() || "null".equals(value) ? null : udtToOptionalParamsTransformer.apply(innerCodec.parse(value));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String format(@Nullable MyOptionalParams MyOptionalParams) {
        return MyOptionalParams == null ? "NULL" : innerCodec.format(optionalParamsToUDTTransformer.apply(MyOptionalParams, userType.newValue()));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public GenericType<MyOptionalParams> getJavaType() {
        return this.javaType;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DataType getCqlType() {
        return cqlType;
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface OptionalParamsToUDTTransformer<F, T> {
        UdtValue apply(F optionalParams, T udt);
    }

}
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
"details":{"type":"INTERNAL","description":"Unexpected runtime exception : Codec not found for requested operation: [UDT(my_keyspace.my_optional_params) <-> com.api.model.MyOptionalParams]","details":{"statusCode":"500"},"stacktrace":"com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.codec.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [UDT(my_keyspace.my_optional_params) <-> com.api.model.MyOptionalParams]\n\tat com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.createCodec(CachingCodecRegistry.java:609)\n\tat com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry$1.load(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:95)\n\tat com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry$1.load(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:92)\n\tat com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527)\n\tat com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2276)\n\tat com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)\n\tat com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)\n\tat com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951)\n\tat com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3973)\n\tat com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4957)\n\tat com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4963)\n\tat com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry.getCachedCodec(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:117)\n\tat com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.codecFor(CachingCodecRegistry.java:215)\n\tat com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.data.SettableByIndex.set(SettableByIndex.java:132)\n\tat com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.data.SettableByName.set(SettableByName.java:166)\n\tat com.dao.impl.cassandra.MyDummyDao.storeData(MyDummyDao.java:23)
```

I am getting below exception

```
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.codec.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [UDT(my_keyspace.my_optional_params) <-> com.api.model.MyOptionalParams]
```

Although, issue is resolved after pod restart, but still root cause is not clear and we have to restart the pod at least once during every migration which is not acceptable.

**Please suggest, any other alternative or migration rules to be followed doing UDT changes, to prevent the exception & the pod restart**.

Software Versions:
Java: 1.8
Cassandra: 3.11